# How do I find std.error with error propagation and for extrapolated data?

Tags: r, python, standard-deviation, error-propagation

I have a table with different means. Some of the data is predicted future change, and the rest I have extrapolated.

```
             % tree cover           Δdeciduous fraction           changed deciduous
2050-2075    10 ± 11 %              10 ± 9  %                     121 ± ?? %
2075-2100    15 ± 17 %              15 ± ?? %                     132 ± ?? %
```

So the changes in tree cover for 2050-2075 and 2075-2100 I predicted with some climate models, the changes in deciduous tree fraction for 2050-2075 other people predicted. Now I have extrapolated their findings of `Δdeciduous fraction` to the future, but I do not think I can extrapolate the standard deviation for them, as they all depend on each of the future models' mean and std.dev found.

Also, I want to find the accumulated standard deviation for the `changed deciduous` based on both my standard deviation and the standard deviation of `deciduous fraction`.

1. Is there a way to extrapolate this standard deviation for the future?
2. How would you find the standard deviation of the `changed deciduous` with error propagation?

Comment: I'm having trouble following your explanation of the issue but usually you would use the extrapolation procedure to derive the uncertainty of extrapolation. Personally, I like doing a monte-carlo simulation if feasible.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up extrapolating the standard deviation for the future prediction of `deciduous tree` just as I did with the mean, hence `12`.
For error propagation, I calculated the multiplication or division error propagation as,

```
Q = np.sqrt((11/10)**2 + (9/10)**2) = 1.42
Qf = (10/10) * 1.42 = 1.42

Q = Sqrt((std.dev1/mean1)**2 + (std.dev2/mean2)**2)
Qf = (mean1/mean2) * Q
```